# where to source images for personas

Tags: resources, personas, graphics

I've always used istockphoto to find images for personas but I'm finding it increasingly difficult to find 'real' looking people. I feel that the more real they look the more believable they are. But most of the images on istock are smiling models. Any ideas where I can find a good source of believable head and shoulders shots of real people?

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/search/?q=portrait&l=commderiv&ct=0&mt=all&adv=1

Answer (score 14):

Flickr is a good source since you can look for Creative Commons licensed images. If you use your personas as an internal tool within your organization http://www.exactitudes.com/ is a great resource.

Comment: No problem Lisa. I find it great too! Nice piece of art as well!

Comment: It should be forbidden to post that site on a UX forum ;-)

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for real people try the real world ;-)

Why not just go and take some picture of your users. You're right there's nothing like a cheesy model shot to damage a persona.  We use picture from our customer base. When we do user testing we ask if we can take a picture and ask them to sign a release to say they are happy for us to hold on file as a persona image.

Answer (score 4):

Flickr has millions of photos with suitable licences. You could also try a free stock site such as http://sxc.hu - the photos won't look quite as artificial as those on iStock.

Answer (score 2):

**Facebook** - I know a couple of people who trawl through their friends on Facebook and then just ask them for permission to use their photo. You can't get much more real than that!

Comment: Thats a great idea. But I don't have enough friends...sniff ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably somewhat illicit, but online personals are a great place to look. The images tend to be less posed and the search interface lets you winnow down on specific attributes.

Just be smart about how you use them. If you expect the personas will be distributed broadly or publicly, go with stock.